# How to scroll to a particular <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I send a user to a url where it will automatically scroll to a given `<li>`?

E.g mysite.com/something.html#someItem

have him scroll to

```
<ul>
   <li id='someItem'>Something here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly that.
Your code will work as-is.

Comment: This is absolutely true, but since this is marked with [jquery], I asume 'scroll' means 'scroll with animation'.

Comment: @Ben: I believe so, but I'm not certain about IE6.

Comment: @SLaks: nobody is certain about IE6. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of examples of scrolling to (any) element using jQuery. There's even plugins that'll do it for you, like [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). :-)

If you want a (really) simple example, here it is:

```
function scrollTo(selector) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
    }, 1000,'easeInOut');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an anchor tag. Like this:

```
<ul>
   <li id='someItem'>
       <a name='someItem'></a>
       Something here
   </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: markup

Comment: You may have been downvoted for invalid markup, but you're right: this is what the anchor tag is for.

Comment: Not true, the id attribute can be the target of the hash value in the url. No anchor required.